# How to change dataframe when button is pressed in Bokeh?

Tags: python, bokeh

I am trying to design a front end display for my dataframe.I want to put a button ,selecting which filters my dataframe.I have tried reading documentation and sample examples but till now I haven't succeeded.
Here is my code for reference:

```
source = ColumnDataSource(data=dict())
act=""

def act_good():
    global act
    act='Good'

def update():
    current = data[data['Activity']==act]
    source.data = {
        'Tag'             :current.Tag,
        'UpdateQuality'   : current.UpdateQuality,
        'Activity' : current.Activity
    }


checkbox_act_good = RadioButtonGroup(
        labels=["Activity Good"])
checkbox_act_good.on_click(act_good())


columns = [
    TableColumn(field="Tag", title="Tag"),
    TableColumn(field="UpdateQuality", title="Quality"),
    TableColumn(field="Activity", title="Activity")
]

data_table = DataTable(source=source, columns=columns, width=800)
controls = widgetbox(slider,button,checkbox_group,but)
table = widgetbox(data_table)
curdoc().add_root(row(controls, table))
update()
```

This is my first time using bokeh.

Answer (score 1):

You can update in different ways. For example you can create a new ColumnDataSource and update the DataTable source like this:

```
from bokeh.models import ColumnDataSource
from bokeh.models.widgets.tables import DataTable, TableColumn
from bokeh.models.widgets.buttons import Button
from bokeh.layouts import column
from bokeh.io import curdoc


columns = [
    TableColumn(field="x", title="X"),
    TableColumn(field="y", title="Y"),
]
init_source = ColumnDataSource(data=dict(x=[''],y=['']))
table = DataTable(
    source=init_source,
    columns=columns,
    reorderable=False,
)

def update_table():
    new_source = ColumnDataSource(dict(
        x=[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6],
        y=[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6],
    ))
    table.source.data = new_source.data

bt = Button(
    label="Update Table",
    button_type="success",
    width=50
)

bt.on_click(update_table)

curdoc().add_root(column(children=[table, bt]))
```

Launch this file with `bokeh serve --show filepath/file.py`. You can use a DataFrame as CDS argument like this: `ColumnDataSource(df)` in order to create the CDS.

Comment: This is very helpful.  there is a small typo though - it should read "TableColumn(field="y", title="Y"),"

Comment: Thanks, I have corrected it @prk